# After upgrading to google maps api 3.17 all fails

Tags: google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

I get this error in the api's main.js `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPlace: unknown property attributes`

Can't figure out what is causing it. Or what specific functionality is failing. Will update question when I fin out more.

All worked in v3.16. I am now using maps api 3.19 with gmap3 5.1.1

Any ideas to what it could be would be helpful

**Update:**

It is the place: place, part in the below that causes it:

```
        marker: {
            options: {
                icon:
                    new google.maps.MarkerImage('/media/img/map_markers/map_marker_' + classname + '.png',
                        new google.maps.Size(37, 31),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(14, 31),
                        new google.maps.Size(37, 31)
                    ),
                place: place,
                draggable:true
            },
```

Comment: Can you show where you're getting place from?

Comment: The MarkerImage class is deprecated, use [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) instead.

Comment: Also 1.17 and 1.19 are the version of what?  Google Maps API 3 has versions 3.17, 3.18 and 3.19.

Comment: @duncan my mistake, fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that place under marker > options has become a used key by the google api.

Changed place to myplace and you are up and running again:

```
marker: {
        options: {
            icon:
                new google.maps.MarkerImage('/media/img/map_markers/map_marker_' + classname + '.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(37, 31),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                    new google.maps.Point(14, 31),
                    new google.maps.Size(37, 31)
                ),
            myplace: place,
            draggable:true
        },
```